# Proper definition of "order" of spherical harmonics?

Tags: spherical-harmonics

I'm looking into spherical harmonics, and the term 'order' seems to be used quite inconsistently.

In google's spherical harmonics framework (https://github.com/google/spherical-harmonics), the constant spherical harmonic is called order 0
so the total number of coefficients is (order + 1)^2

In NVIDIA's "Efficient Spherical Harmonics Evaluation" (http://jcgt.org/published/0002/02/06/) the constant spherical harmonic is called order 1, so the total number of coefficients is order^2

In the wikipedia article about spherical harmonics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) the order can be negative and positive and describes the 'horizontal' index, with all zonal spherical harmonics being order 0.

Obviously there doesn't seem to be consensus about this - but can someone argue for one of them being the most proper use of the term 'order' in regards to spherical harmonics and why?